# Why doesnt my program draw the houses from the arrayList?

Tags: java, android, arraylist, libgdx

I want in my game to draw houses (huis = house) that fall continuesly at the sides of the screen. (On the grass as the 'world' moves downwards.' 
[image: screenshot]

But,having this code, and no trouble in the logcat i dont know why it doesnt draw the houses.
The 'main flow' of this code goes as follows: I created an arraylist that holds the house.png. Then through a for loop it adds a house when there is some space between it.

```
package com.mygdx.Papermadness;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationListener;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.InputAdapter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.audio.Music;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.TextureWrap;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Sprite;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ShapeRenderer;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ShapeRenderer.ShapeType;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Rectangle;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2;

public class Papermadness extends InputAdapter implements ApplicationListener {
    private SpriteBatch huisBatch;
    private Texture huisTexture;
    private SpriteBatch batch;
    private Sprite sprite;
    private SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
    private Sprite huisSprite;
    private Texture spriteTexture;
    private float scrollTimer = 0.0f;
    private float huisVelocity = 200f;
    private float huisLinksY = 2100;
    private float huisLinksX = 0;
    private float huisRechtsY = 2100;
    private float huisRechtsX = 903;
    private Sprite huis;
    private ArrayList<Sprite> huisArray = new ArrayList<Sprite>();
    Rectangle bounds;
    Player player;
    Paper paper;
    ShapeRenderer sr;

    @Override
    public void create() {
        player = new Player(new Vector2(50, 100), new Vector2(100, 100));
        paper = new Paper(new Vector2(Gdx.input.getX(),Gdx.graphics.getHeight()-Gdx.input.getY()), new Vector2(50, 50));
        sr = new ShapeRenderer();
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch();
        huisBatch = new SpriteBatch();
        huisTexture = new Texture("huis.png");
        huisSprite = new Sprite(huisTexture);
        spriteTexture = new Texture("b2.png");
        spriteTexture.setWrap(TextureWrap.Repeat, TextureWrap.Repeat);
        sprite = new Sprite(spriteTexture);
        sprite.setSize(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
    }

    @Override
    public void render() {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        float delta = Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
        scrollTimer += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
        if (scrollTimer > 2f)
            scrollTimer = 0.0f;
        sprite.setV(scrollTimer + 2);
        sprite.setV2(scrollTimer);
        player.update();
        paper.update();
        spriteBatch.begin();
        sprite.draw(spriteBatch);
        for (int i = 0; i < huisArray.size(); i++) {
            huisArray.get(i).setY(huisArray.get(i).getY() - huisVelocity * delta);
            if (huisArray.get(i).getY() <= 200) {
                huisArray.remove(i);
                i--;
            }               
        }
        if (huisArray.size() > 0 && huisArray.get(0).getY() < 1200) {
            addNewHuis();
        }
        huisBatch.begin();
        for (int i = 0; i < huisArray.size(); i++) {
            huisBatch.draw(huisArray.get(i), huisArray.get(i).getX(), huisArray.get(i).getY());
        }
        huisLinksY -= huisVelocity * delta;
        huisRechtsY -= huisVelocity * delta;
        batch.begin();
        player.draw(batch);
        paper.draw(batch);
        batch.end();
        sr.begin(ShapeType.Filled);
        sr.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        sr.setColor(Color.RED);
        sr.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        sr.rect(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - Gdx.input.getY(), paper.getSize().x,
        paper.getSize().y);
        sr.end();
    }

    private void addNewHuis() {           
        huis = new Sprite();
        huis.setY(1800);
        huisArray.add(0, huis);
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Without actual code we won't be able to help you because we don't know how you _actually_ implemented your draw loop.

Comment: There's no way we can possibly diagnose this without more information and preferably seeing code. You should indicate what diagnostics you've tried yourself (e.g. logging) too...

Comment: whoops forgot to add it lol !

Comment: Format that code please.

Comment: Why did you post all of the stub methods that have no bearing on your question? If they don't do anything, they can't possibly be relevant to the problem you're having.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my point of view, your house array is empty - so it does not have anything to draw. You create huisArray, but you do not add anything to it. So when you render() is called first, huisArray.size() == 0 is true.

```
for (int i = 0; i < huisArray.size(); i++) { //you do not step into this piece of code.
            huisArray.get(i).setY(huisArray.get(i).getY() - huisVelocity * delta);
            if (huisArray.get(i).getY() <= 200) {
                huisArray.remove(i);
                i--;
            }               
        }
```

Then, you want to add a house if there are some houses there. But it's still empty so you do not add anything.

```
if (huisArray.size() > 0 && huisArray.get(0).getY() < 1200) {
    addNewHuis();
}
```

And you attempt to draw still empty array:

```
huisBatch.begin();
for (int i = 0; i < huisArray.size(); i++) { //you do not step into this piece of code either
    huisBatch.draw(huisArray.get(i), huisArray.get(i).getX(), huisArray.get(i).getY());
}
```

**Solution**: Add one-two huisSprite to huisArray in create().

Hope it helps :)

Comment: and how I am I supposed to do that? Sorry I am quite a beginner

Comment: in create() after you created huisSprite add a line: huisArray.add(huisSprite) OR addNewHuise().

Comment: btw, in your addNewHuise() `huis = new Sprite()` - shouldn't it be `new Sprite(huisTexture)`?

Comment: I have made those 2 changes but it still doesnt work :(

Comment: did you try logging or debug? do you have objects in huisArray when you enter render()?

Comment: Made it work! changed huisArray.add(huisSprite) to addNewHuis(); did the trick. Thanks for your effort